# React Noob - onChange Element Loses Focus

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a basic login page that accepts user credentials and submits them to a login api. the problem is that when the `onChange` event fires, to set the user credentials, the element loses focus. Should I not be updating the credentials with `onChange`?

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Row, Col, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Checkbox, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {credentials: {username: '', password: ''}};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSave = this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const credentials = this.state.credentials;
    credentials[field] = event.target.value;
    return this.setState({credentials: credentials});
    console.log(event);
  }

  onSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.credentials);
    this.props.actions.logInUser(this.state.credentials);
  }

  render() {
    function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
      return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
          <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
          {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }

    const formInstance = (


          <Col xs={12} md={8} mdOffset={2}>
            <form>
              <FieldGroup
                name="username"
                label="Username"
                placeholder="Enter username"
                value={this.state.credentials.username}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <FieldGroup
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                value={this.state.credentials.password}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <Checkbox checked readOnly>
                Checkbox
              </Checkbox>

              <Button type="submit" onClick={this.onSave}>
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Col>

    );
    return formInstance;
  }
}
```

***Edit***

Working when FieldGroup is moved to separate component, as suggested.

***common/FieldGroup.jsx***

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class FieldGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('props');
    console.log(props);
    this.id = props.name;
    this.label = props.label;
    this.help = props.placeholder;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <FormGroup controlId={this.props.name}>
        <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl {...this.props} />
        {this.props.help && <HelpBlock>{this.props.help}</HelpBlock>}
      </FormGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

***components/Login.jsx***

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Col, Checkbox, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import FieldGroup from '../common/FieldGroup';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {credentials: {username: '', password: ''}};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSave = this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const credentials = this.state.credentials;
    credentials[field] = event.target.value;
    return this.setState({credentials: credentials});
  }

  onSave(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.credentials);
    this.props.actions.logInUser(this.state.credentials);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col xs={12} md={8} mdOffset={2}>
        <form>
          <FieldGroup
            name="username"
            label="Username"
            placeholder="Enter username"
            value={this.state.credentials.username}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <FieldGroup
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={this.state.credentials.password}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <Checkbox checked readOnly>
            Checkbox
          </Checkbox>

          <Button type="submit" onClick={this.onSave}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Col>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem (as I write it's been answered), but defining the `FieldGroup` component within the parent's `render` function is very odd. I'd clearly move that out and define it as its own stateless component, either in its own file (if you plan to reuse) or before the parent `Login` component.

Comment: Doing this will probably also fix the problem. Right now, you create a new stateless component  `FieldGroup` on each render, which will cause the old dom tree to unmount and a new one to mount, losing focus in the process.

Comment: @jaxx moving FieldGroup to separate component worked, thanks. Am I using props correctly in the render function i.e., is {...this.props} correct?

Comment: @Oblosys You're right, i didn't even think of that. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @neridaj Your code is probably working as is, but I think you're not using that spread/rest operator as you should. Also, you should make your FieldGroup stateless as it doesn't uses state (and doesn't require it). I'd show you what I mean, but I'm not sure I should compose an answer that has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: @Jaxx No problem! It's pretty subtle, as `{FieldGroup({id: 'username', label=.., ..})}` instead of `<FieldGroup ...>` would work just fine, without the unmounting and focus loss.

Comment: @Oblosys You should compose the answer (including the alternative, correct syntax you gave above), I'm sure this could be pretty useful.

Comment: @neridaj See the following pastebin for a stateless, simpler version of your `FieldGroup` component: https://pastebin.com/mMWQhgyx

Comment: @Jaxx if you'd like to answer it that's totally fine by me, but if you'd like me to answer I'll put something together tomorrow morning. It's an interesting issue.

Comment: @Oblosys Yeah you should do it, I'm clearly interested. Also, I fixed neridaj's problem accidentally, while you provided a rational explanation. On top of it, I'm really curious about that other syntax you gave.. I'm guessing in that case, there would be no actual `FieldGroup` component, just a `FieldGroup` rendering subroutine, hence no mounting/unmounting?

Comment: @jaxx, yeah, I figured there was a better way to write that. However, getting unexpected token from line 4: `export default const FieldGroup = ({ name, label, help, ...props }) => {`

Comment: @jaxx, that gives another error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FieldGroup is not defined` I can't find this export default pattern anywhere, I just see this pattern being used: `export default class Group extends React.Component {}`. This worked: `const FieldGroup = ({ name, label, help, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={name}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}

export default FieldGroup;`

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question, as it shows that even though stateless functional components (SFC's) don't have lifecycle methods, they do get unmounted and remounted when they change. This isn't documented all that clearly, but can be seen in the [react implementation notes](https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html#updating-composite-components) (in the case of SFC's, `type` is the SFC function itself).

Because `FieldGroup` is declared inside `render`, a new function is created on each rendering, which causes the previous SFC component in the virtual dom to unmount and be replaced by a new one. This will happen even when their renderings are exactly the same. As a consequence, any descendent input elements will unmount and remount, losing state and focus in the process.

If you simply call the SFC rather than instantiate it (i.e. `{SFC({...sfcProps})}` instead of `<SFC {...sfcProps}/>`, no virtual dom component is created for the SFC itself, and no remounting will occur if the rendering stays the same.

This snippet shows a local SFC, both instantiated and called as a function, as well as a regular top-level SFC. Only the bottom two inputs work correctly.

```js
const SFC = ({rerender}) => <input onChange={rerender}/>

class App extends React.Component {
  rerender = () => this.forceUpdate();

  render () {
    const LocalSFC = ({rerender}) => <input onChange={rerender}/>
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Local SFC (loses state & focus on typing): <LocalSFC rerender={this.rerender}/></div>
        <div>Local function application (works fine): {LocalSFC({rerender: this.rerender})}</div>
        <div>Regular SFC (works fine): <SFC rerender={this.rerender}/></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

So to fix the problem, you could replace each `<FieldGroup name=.. label=.. ../>` by `{FieldGroup({name: .., label:.., ..})}`, but it makes more sense to do as Jaxx suggested and simply lift `FieldGroup` out of the `Login` class to the top-level or a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

Returning inside an `onChange` function will cause it to lose an element's focus.  Remove `return` from your `onChange` function.

You do not need to return `setState`.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it didn't fix the issue. I actually coped that code from here: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/jwt-authentication-with-react-redux/