# TextField DeSelected onChange - React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders multiple text-fields. My state contains the information about all the text-fields I have in the component.

My state looks something like this,

```
this.state.list = [
    {
        id: "some-string",
        name: "something"
    },
    {
        id: "some-other-string-id",
        name: "some name"
    }
]
```

And handler function looks like this,

```
public handleChange(event: any) {

    var index = this.state.list.findIndex((elem) => {
        return elem.id === event.target.id;
    });

    var state = this.state;
    state.list[index].name = event.target.value;

    this.setState(state);
}
```

Rendering,

```
{this.state.list.map((list, i) => {
    <TextField
        id={list.id}
        value={list.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
}
```

It works fine except that it de-selects the text field each time I make a change. How can I avoid that?

Comment: The problem sounds similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777832/react-noob-onchange-element-loses-focus/46791156

Comment: Yup, it sounds like it. But it never been answered. And I am using something like this to call component `<Route exact={true} path="/some-path" component={MyComp} />`

Comment: @HafizTemuri Are you by chance updating the `key` field in a react collection? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { TextField } from "material-ui";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          id: "some-string",
          name: "something"
        },
        {
          id: "some-other-string-id",
          name: "some name"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    const list = [...this.state.list];
    list[index].name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ list });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map((list, i) => (
          <TextField
            id={list.id}
            value={list.name}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You were mutating state as well in your handleChange function.  My updated answer keeps state pure and could help solve your issue.

Comment: I have my state initialized in my constructor. `this.state = { list: this.props.list };` I have tried your solution. It still de-selecting the fields.

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring your function as public?  Perhaps you could try changing `public handleChange(event: any){ ... }` to `handleChange = (event: any) => { ... };`  Doing so would bind your function to the component and could possibly solve your issue.

Comment: If you aren't using es6 syntax, then try declaring your function like this: `handleChange (event: any){ ... };`  and bind your function inside the constructor like so:  `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example of what a bound handler looks like in your situation

Comment: I have tried without having handler function public. It still the same :(

Comment: This works fine when I run it... Are you sure the issue is stemming from this component?

Comment: What else it could be? I am calling the function like that `<Route exact={true} path="/some-path" component={MyComp} />` and I can't think of any other thing that could cause an issue.

Comment: I've updated it one more time with code thats running for me.  Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I actually had a typo in `id=list.name` instead of `id=list.id`. That's why it was rendering each time. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   class TextFields extends Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
           list: [
               {
                   id: "one",
                   name: "First Field"
               },
               {
                id: "two",
                name: "Second Field"
            },
            {
                id: "three",
                name: "Third Field"
            }
           ]
       }
       this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }

   onChange(event) {
       var index = this.state.list.findIndex(elem => {
           return elem.id === event.target.id
       });

       var state = this.state;
       state.list[index].name = event.target.value;
       // not needed
       //state.list[index].autofocus = true;

       this.setState(state);
   }

   render () {
    return <div>{this.state.list.map((list, i) => {
        return <TextField 
        id={list.id}
        value={list.name}
        onChange={this.onChange}/>  
    })} </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: It still the same! It loses focus on change

Comment: Which package are using for your TextField?

Comment: `material ui`  package

Answer (score 0):

```
   class TextFields extends Component {
   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
           list: [
               {
                   id: "one",
                   name: "First Field",
                   autofocus: false,
               },
               {
                id: "two",
                name: "Second Field",
                autofocus: false,
            },
            {
                id: "three",
                name: "Third Field"
            }
           ]
       }
       this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }

   onChange(event) {
       var index = this.state.list.findIndex(elem => {
           return elem.id === event.target.id
       });

       var state = this.state;
       state.list[index].name = event.target.value;
       state.list[index].autofocus = true;

       this.setState(state);
   }

   render () {
    return <div>{this.state.list.map((list, i) => {
        return <TextField 
        id={list.id}
        value={list.name}
        onChange={this.onChange}/>  
    })} </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't mind the autofocus property in textField object.

Comment: It saying that it doesn't have the property of autofocus.

Comment: I also tried with `e.target.autofocus = true;` that doesn't work either.

Comment: Remove this line 'state.list[index].autofocus = true'. You can use the updated answer

Comment: After removing that line. It behaves the same as the issue I am having.