# Defining a sub-render function in render vs. a React component

Tags: reactjs

I came upon a React puzzle recently...

This works fine:

```js
const App = () => {
  const renderFoo = () => (<p>Foo</p>) 
  return (<div>{renderFoo()}</div>)
}
```

Of course, you could also pull out `Foo` entirely:

```
const Foo = () => (<p>Foo</p>) 
const App = () => {
  return (<div><Foo /></div>)
}
```

But, putting `Foo` definition inside `App` leads to terrible behavior.

```
const App = () => {
  const Foo = () => (<p>Foo</p>) 
  return (<div><Foo /></div>)
}
```

With the latter, if you did that with a form then you lose focus every time you make a change. ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewsouthpaw/pen/OJyXLLv))

```js
const BadTimes = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const RenderForm = () => (
    <input value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <RenderForm />
    </div>
  )
}
```

So I'm wondering: **why is this the case?** What's the difference between `{renderForm()}` vs. `<RenderForm />` such that the behavior completely changes?

Side note: please keep efficiency discussions out of this (e.g. "Well you shouldn't do it anyway because you're redefining the function on every render"). I want to know the technical side of what's going on.

Comment: One is a simple function that returns renderable JSX. The other is an actual Component subject to all the react component lifecycles and processes. I think it's obvious how one has much more overhead.

Comment: @DrewReese as far as TypeScript is concerned, both `rederForm` and `RenderForm` are `() => JSX.Element`.  I don't think the question is about the overhead, but instead **why** they cause a different behavior when they seem almost identical at their core.

Comment: @zero298 True, even at the javascript level, they are just functions after all. The React framework is what interprets them differently.

Comment: Yeah that's what baffles me, they're just functions after all. My best guess was the React framework takes the JSX version `<RenderForm />` as some sort of signal to "componentize" the function whereas `renderForm()` doesn't bother, even though they're exactly the same shape. But I was hoping for someone with a deeper knowledge to illuminate. :-)

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question a while ago. I think it explains what you want to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777832/react-noob-onchange-element-loses-focus/46791156#46791156

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, that:

1. `renderForm()` returns `{ type: "input", ... }`
2. `<RenderForm />` returns `{ type: RenderForm, ... }`

In case 1. React sees the same element in the virtual DOM for every render cycle,
in case 2. it is a different element in every render cycle.

#### The `RenderForm()`

The function `RenderForm()` is a new, different function in every render cycle, which happens to do the same thing as the previous function *(which was created in the previous render cycle)*.

The function `RenderForm()` returns the same React element in both cases *(using `<RenderForm />` and using `renderForm()`)*, which is the HTML input element.

E.g. consider this illustration:

```
const BadTimes = () => {
    const [ text, setText ] = React.useState( '' );

    const RenderForm = () => {
        return React.createElement( "input", { value: text, onChange: e => setText( e.target.value ) } );
    };

    const elementFromFunction = RenderForm(); // <-- same as `<input value=... />`, i.e. `React.createElement( 'input', ... )`
    const elementFromComponent = <RenderForm />; // <-- transpiled to React.createElement( RenderForm )

    return <div>
        <p>from function: { elementFromFunction }</p>
        <p>from component: { elementFromComponent }</p>
    </div>;
};
```

where `RenderForm()` always returns the React element:

```
{
  "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"),
  type:  "input",
  key:   null,
  ref:   null,
  props: Object { value: "", onChange: onChange(e) },
  ...
}
```

#### `RenderForm()` vs. `<RenderForm />`

But the JSX syntax `<RenderForm />` will be transpiled to `React.createElement( RenderForm )`,
while the javascript function call `RenderForm()` will stay unchanged *(i.e. is not transpiled)*.

So **(1.)** `RenderForm()` returns that `{ type: "input", ... }` element directly, and:

```
<div>{ RenderForm() }</div>
```

is in essence the same as writing:

```
<div><input value={ text } onChange={ e => setText( e.target.value ) } /></div>
```

while **(2.)** `<RenderForm />` returns that `{ type: RenderForm, ... }` element, which has a reference to the newly created
`RenderForm` function, so it is a different element in every render cycle:

```
<div><RenderForm /></div>
```

still refers to the `RenderForm` function, which still needs to be executed, recursively *(but also still in the same render cycle)*:

```
<div>{ React.createElement( RenderForm ) }</div>
```

#### Component- / element-updates

The React element created by `RenderForm()` refers to the string `"input"`, but `React.createElement( RenderForm )` refers to the function `RenderForm` (aka. React *functional component*).

The `"input"` React element stays always the same DOM element (referentially equal), but `RenderForm` is a new function in every render cycle, so `React.createElement( RenderForm )` creates a new React element, which in turn creates a new `input` DOM element.

The old `<RenderForm />` (including its `input`) gets unmounted, the `focus` is set to the `body`, the new `<RenderForm />` (including a new `input`) gets mounted, and the `onFocus` handler is attached, but the `input` hasn't the focus yet, of course.